# How to add after styles to material ui Tab Scroll Button separately for left and right buttons

Tags: material-ui

The documentation shows that the default class for tab scroll button is `MuiTabScrollButton-root`. I am looking to add `::before` to the left button and `::after` to the right button.

Code for tab is very standard so I added a code sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-forest-x62tv?file=/src/App.js

How to do this preferably within the component css (using classes.something) instead of a global css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to target `.MuiTabScrollButton-root:first-child` and `.MuiTabScrollButton-root:last-child` to get the left and right buttons respectively

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  customTabsStyle: {
    "& .MuiTabScrollButton-root:first-child::before": {
      content: "'L'"
    },
    "& .MuiTabScrollButton-root:last-child::after": {
      content: "'R'"
    }
  }
}));

<Tabs classes={{ root: classes.customTabsStyle }} />
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-wing-6ryss]